# Get byte from hex number

Tags: c#

I want to get the most and least significate byte from a hex number.

For example to get 'A':

```
ushort hex = ushort.Parse(string.Format("{0:x}", 'A'));
```

And then I can get the most significate byte by:

```
(byte)hex >> 8
```

...which is 41.

But how do I do with 'J' for instance, 'J' is "4A" and it cannot be parsed to a short. How can I convert it to a byte value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's really confusing to me what you're trying to get here... the value 'A' in hex is just (decimal) 10. Currently you're performing conversions to UTF-16 code units for no obvious reason. Next, "J" isn't a valid hex digit, so it can't be any part of "getting a byte from a hex number". Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: How exactly would you like to parse `J`? The parsing above uses `A` as the numerical value 10, of which `A` is the hexadecimal notation. What exactly would you like to do with `J`?

Comment: you have to clarify more what you want; I get exception with your first line

Comment: Please add expected results to your question.

Comment: I guess what you want is get a char ascii code in hex and then get the MSB but..the question is why? what are you trying to archieve?

Answer (score 6):

There is an overload of `ushort.Parse` for that:

```
char ch = (char)ushort.Parse("4A", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Then you cast it to `(char)`: `char ch = (char)`

or

```
byte ch = byte.Parse("4A", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

if you need a `byte`.